# Проксируем не весь location NGINX

Tags: nginx, rewrite, location

Есть локейшен, в который приходят запросы от клиентов, нужно определить если это мобильные устройства то редиректить или реврайтить их на мобильный сайт и другой `URL` но не могу сообразить как это сделать. Определить мобильного клиента получилось, пытаюсь настроить реврайт.

```
location /Missing {
    if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) { rewrite ^/Missing http://mobile-stie/status?code=$request_uri;}
```

Проблема в том, что нужно из запроса убрать `/Missing` а всё остальное реврайтить, не знаю как сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать вот так:

location /Missing {
        if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) { rewrite ^/Missing/(.*)$ http://mobile-site/status?code=$1 last;}

Теперь, если вы заходите с десктопа на www.desktop.com/Missing/12345/true то получаете ответ большого сайта. А если с мобильно устройства то ссылка меняется на
http://mobile-site/status?code=12345/true